# email sheet can't be canceled?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am opening an email sheet to send a file. It works great except that I can't go back to my app.

When I hit cancel button, it ask if to delete or save draft, and stay there. It doesn't go back to app page.

code:

```
//send email log-------------------------
    NSLog(@"mail");
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];

    picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    //Fill in the email as you see fit
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"name@gmail.com"]; 
    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];


    NSArray *paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *dataPath = [[paths2 objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.txt"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
    [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/txt" fileName:@"Test.txt"];

    NSString *emailBody = @"Test   ";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [picker setSubject:@"hardware test ##   "];

    //display the view
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:picker.view];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
```

**EDIT:**

I have added the function suggested in the answer right here, he calls the function when I hit cancel, but it stays in that sheet.
I have to say that I am using a cclayer (cocos2d) so the layer is defined with :

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer< MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Any other suggestion ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement the delegate method

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
        didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
```

and dismiss the view controller in there:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
```

UPDATE:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
            didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

Comment: ok i have changed it to: (MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result , but it STILL does not work, i hit cancel and then i cant hit it anymore-but it stay in that sheet. any help ?

Comment: thanks, read my former response , i have changed that, the function been called when i hit cancel, but it does not quite the sheet. i have tried also: picker.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated but nothing .

Comment: Oh, I just realized you are adding the MFMailComposeViewController's view directly to your OpenGL view. That's really not a good idea. You can dismiss it by calling `[picker.view removeFromSuperview;]`. But instead you should either add it to your OpenGL view's superview. Or even better, call `[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];`. This will of course only work in a view controller subclass.

Comment: thanks a lot ! [picker.view removeFromSuperview]; worked ! the other one you wrote did not. can you explain why i had to change that ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11185/discussion-between-drummerb-and-user1280535)

Comment: its frozen when i go back to my scene with [picker.view removeFromSuperview;].

Comment: Because you call `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];` after showing the email editor view.
It's a good idea to stop animation when it's not visible.
But you have to restart it again, once the editor view is dismissed.
And I think you're not supposed to call stopAnimation, but pause.
So, call `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]` instead of stopAnimation
And in addition to removing the editor in the delegate method call `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];`